# readelf reports so file as NEEDED, but no functions (or other symbols) is used from it

Tags: linux, dependencies, executable, elf

Readelf reports, that libutil.so.1 is needed by ssh utility:

```
$readelf -s /usr/bin/ssh | grep libutil
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libutil.so.1]
```

As nm says, libutil.so.1 has only 6 external symbols:

```
$nm -D /lib64/libutil.so.1 | grep "T "
000000331e0015a0 T forkpty
000000331e000fa0 T login
000000331e0010f0 T login_tty
000000331e001190 T logout
000000331e0012e0 T logwtmp
000000331e0013d0 T openpty
```

But these symbols not referenced from ssh:

```
$nm -D /usr/bin/ssh | grep forkpty
$nm -D /usr/bin/ssh | grep login
$nm -D /usr/bin/ssh | grep login_tty
$nm -D /usr/bin/ssh | grep logout
$nm -D /usr/bin/ssh | grep logwtmp
$nm -D /usr/bin/ssh | grep openpty

(grep not showing any matches)
```

What's going on? Why library referenced as NEEDED, but no symbols from it used? This is not sole example. I met many such "empty" references, while analysing dependencies of another executables.

Comment: What's the distro you built this app on?

Comment: Distro was Red Hat 6.6, but i do not think it matters.

Comment: it does, on modern distros `--as-needed` is enabled by default so you'd need to use `--no-as-needed` to fix your problem. Redhat 6 seems to be sane though (just checked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DT_NEEDED` tagging is generated by the link editor (`ld`) based on the `-l` flags provided. The default for the GNU link editor and most other editors, with some exceptions, is to create a `DT_NEEDED` tag for each `-l` flag provided.

When using GNU `ld` or `gold`, you can pass `--as-needed` before the `-l` flags to only emit `DT_NEEDED` tags for the libraries that are indeed used. This may still emit not obvious tags if the symbols are actually used indirectly.

I have actually written a significant amount about `--as-needed` and how it works, so you can look through [my blog posts](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/tags/as-needed/) if you are more curious.

Comment: "The default for the GNU link editor ... is to create a DT_NEEDED tag" - isn't  `--as-needed` enabled by default on all modern distros (Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSuse)?

Comment: Can't speak for all of them, but it is not enabled by default on Gentoo Linux yet afaict. At least not in the non-soft version. I think it may be in `gold` though.